# How do i authenticate user in angularJS app ?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, oauth, spring-security

my app has spring for the backend and angular in the front end. 
For authenticating a user, i ask the user for his id and pass, i encrypt using base64 and on server after matching of id and pass, a cookie is sent to the browser in response header, Since my angular app cant access the cookie (because of httponly flag) how should i authenticate and move him to an authorised = true state.

Thank you.

Comment: You take the word of the server for it. If the request is successful, it means the user is authenticated. Since the info is stored in the cookie, your browser will send it across to the server for each request - you don't need to do anything (on the client side).

Comment: okay, do you know some good ref. for this ? like some sample app